# How do I switch chars at certain indexes of a char array?

Tags: java, arrays, char

Lets say I have a char array maze[][] and it contains this:

```
    P . X X .
    . X . . .
    . . . X .
    X X T . .
    . . X . .
```

And I am writing a function that if you want to move down, will bring "P" from maze[0][0]
to maze[1][0] and then bring "." from maze[1][0] to maze[0][0] and so on...

Basically how do I trade the values at 2 indexes in a char array?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  You'll need a temp variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same way you switch values in any two variables: use a temporary variable and do the swap with three assignments:

```
char tmp = maze[r1][c1];
maze[r1][c1] = maze[r2][c2];
maze[r2][c2] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
char temp = maze[1][0];
maze[1][0] = maze[0][0];
maze[0][0] = temp;
```

More generalize form :

```
void trade(char[][] maze,int r1,int c1,int r2,int c2){
    char temp = maze[r2][c2];
    maze[r2][c2] = maze[r1][c1];
    maze[r1][c1] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change using temp variable and swap the value of array element

```
char temp = maze[row1][column0];
maze[row1][column[0] = maze[row2][column2];
maze[row2][coumn2] = temp;
```